# SOAP Faults vs return codes in service operation

Tags: wcf

Suppose that I am designing a service interface similar to this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MakePaymentRequest
{    
    [DataMember]
    public string AccountID { get; set; }        

    [DataMember]
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }                
}

[DataContract]
public class MakePaymentResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ConfirmationID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ReceiptText { get; set; }        
}

[OperationContract]
MakePaymentResponse MakePayment(MakePaymentRequest makePaymentRequest);
```

There are two ways to handle exceptions.

**1) Use return codes**

Include return code into the response

```
    [DataMember]
    public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
```

so that ReturnCode of "000" means success or so on. The downside of this approach is that I would need to have try - catch in the operation method:

```
public MakePaymentResponse MakePayment(MakePaymentRequest makePaymentRequest)
{
    try
    {
       // do stuff and return MakePaymentResponse with success code           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return new MakePaymentResponse { ReturnCode = "999" );
    } 
}
```

**2) Use WCF global exception handling and return SOAP faults**

Add global handler into custom service behavior:

```
public class FaultErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
   // ...
   public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        try
        {
            _log.Error("Exception was caught", error);
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {   
        if (fault == null)
        {
            FaultCode faultCode;
            if (error is ConfigurationErrorsException)
            { 
                faultCode = new FaultCode("Configuration");
            }
            else
            {
                faultCode = new FaultCode("Server error");
            }

            var fe = new FaultException<ReceiverFaultDetail>(new ReceiverFaultDetail("Unexpected error has occured", true), "Exception",  FaultCode.CreateReceiverFaultCode(faultCode));
            MessageFault mf = fe.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, mf, fe.Action);
        }            
    }
}
```

My preference would be the second scenario as it is cleaner and will never fault the channel, but I would like to understand if there's anything that I am missing taking this route.

Comment: I would recommend using both, actually.  You should implement normal exception handling (try-catch) in the service code, and have the global error handler to catch exceptions that are not otherwise caught.

Comment: Why both? What is the benefit for callers to check return codes after every operation? If server sends SOAP fault there will be  FaultException (at least on .Net platform).